# Сохранение в SqLite массива объектов, полученного из json

Tags: android, sqlite, retrofit2

json типа   `"rates":{"AAA":5.023852,"BBB":77.682521}`

Сперва я делал всё вручную, в `AsyncTask` получил `json` , распарсил в свой класс

```
class ModelData {

    private String name;
    private Double value;

    ModelData(String name, Double value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

и кеширую в БД `sqLite` сам `json` ответ. Ведь `List<ModelDate>` мне в sqLite не записать. Вот тут еще подвопрос: верно ли я понимаю что, чтобы сохранить в sqLite объект мы создаем json повторяющий этот объект и сохраняем спокойно как строку в БД. А еще существует `ORMLite`часто слышал, но теперь думаю, что она нужна для хранения объектов в БД. Как она это делает не знаю, может так же создает json автоматически и хранит)

И тут я решил внедрить `retrofit 2`(надо же наконец то) и естественно это потеря некой гибкости и вот проблема: ответ мой парсится

```
@SerializedName("rates")
@Expose
private List<ModelData> ratesList;
```

Но как же мне этот `ratesList` сохранить в `sqLite`.  Я понимаю, что этот лист я могу как то обратно в Json сконвертировать и сохранить, но при чтении из БД придется снова парсить, а этот еще код парсера, хотя один уже есть.

Вот чего я хотел бы: в POJO модели иметь отдельно и распарсенные поля и сам сырой json (какая аннотация нужна чтобы получить json целиком? или что нужно) И так же иметь возможность распарсить полученный из БД json этим же классом POJO модели.

Я думаю это не плохой пример того, как  `retrofit 2` и `sqLite` вместе лишили гибкости и для маленького проекта оказались излишними и выгоду от них получу только, если проект разрастется.

**UPD1** 
Понял, что можно ведь интерфейс к rest api настроить на прием сырого json, типо:

```
@GET("{date}")
Call<JsonObject> getData(@Path("date") String date, @Query("access_key") String accessKey, @Query("base") String  base);
```

Но как мне позже для этого JsonObject использовать POJO модель, чтобы его распарсить Gson конвертером добавленным к ретрофит. Вот это есть то самое что я не понял в этой библиотеке, где и какой метод вообще занимается парсингом. В какой момент конвертер подключается, может где то уже на уровне okhttp3 ... В общем устал ворошить эту библиотеку

Comment: посмотрите на субд, такие как room или requery

Comment: Вообще вам не нужно ничего парсить, помечаете поля аннотацией serializedname, и возвращате объект как есть из метода интерфейса ретрофита, оно будет парсить все "под капотом". Если хотите сами распарсить json в объект, то воспользуйтесь методом fromJson(string, class) у gson. new Gson().fromGson(jsonString, PoJo.class), метод типизированный, вернет вам объект

Comment: Парсингом занимается сгенерированный код, почитайте про annotation processors в java. Можно на этапе прекомпиляции генероровать код, который будет компилироваться, и использоваться. Обычно это используют, когда надо автоматизировать процесс написания однотипного кода - как раз парсинг объектов Gsonом, инъекция View библиотекой ButterKnife, тот же ретрофит, room итд.

Comment: Ну я так и делаю, помечаю поля аннотацией и получаю объект, а потом не могу этот объект в sqLite сохранить (использовать другую Субд не хочу, т.к. все в учебных целях делается и есть кое что сейчас важнее для изучения). Поэтому из метода интерфейса ретрофита я возвращаю сырой json,чтобы его и сохранить в БД,  а вот про fromJson(string, class) я забыл. Это то что нужно чтобы PoJo класс наполнить данными.

Comment: Но что я пока так и не понял, где в ретрофит под капотом тот кусок кода, который PoJo класс наполняет данными..вот тут то мне наверно и надо разобраться с annotation processors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас какие-то экзотические хотелки от аннотаций. Для удобства представления объекта в json я переопределял его `toString` таким образом:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new Gson().toJson(this);
    }
```

В `SQLite` можно конечно сериализованный объект запихать, но не лучше ли записать его поля - каждое в свою колонку. Та же `ORMLite` так и делает, только без Вашего участия. Это даст возможность делать выборки по значениям полей с сортировкой и прочими `SQL`-прелестями. Хотя у `SQLite` есть свой `json-API` всё же удобней работать когда всё на своём месте.

### UPD

`Retrofit` для того и создан, что бы его пользователь не парил себе мозг, а просто указал тип модели в своём интерфейсе и забрал готовый объект этой модели из `Response`. Если Вам нужно вмешаться в этот процесс и спарсить json в модель как-то по-особенному - читайте документацию, статьи, примеры по `Gson` - он много чего умеет. https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md

Comment: То что надо. Я не знал, что Gson может представить класс обратно в json (хотя это следует из того, что использовал его для обратного процесса). Да я примерно понял зачем ORMLite нужен. А что насчет Retrifit , да он облегчит, но вот что выходит: в интерфейсе указан тип модели, теперь у меня есть класс, но сырой json утерян, а в sqLite как раз и нужен был этот  json и мне приходится снова его делать. Проще принять в интерфейсе jsonObject или ResponceBody сохранить его и распарсить в тип модели. Но я Вас хорошо понял и мне просто надо получше взглянуть на функционал Gson.

Comment: что то я ошибся в своем вопросе. Тот json что у меня есть отказывается парситься в мою Модель данных.   
'SerializedName("rates")
Expose
private List<ModelData> ratesList;'  В этом вопросе всё уже есть, поэтому не хотел бы отдельный однотипный создавать. Можете подсказать в чем я тут не прав, если вместо списка ModelData ставил HashMap было всё норм

Comment: `@SerializedName("rates")` 
                                                                                 
 `@Expose`                                                                                                          
 `private List<ModelData> ratesList;'  `  Вот , наконец то я разобрался как в комментариях код выделять, а коммент что выше уже править не могу, 5 мин прошли пока я разбирался. Тем не менее всё в строчку...

Comment: Править нельзя, но удалять ненужные комменты можно в любое время. Объект не может быть спарсен в список без кастомной десериализации. Из коробки `Gson` умеет парсит `json-object` в карту, а `json-array` в массив и список.